# this *was* a mistake vs this *is* a mistake

Tags: grammar

I have the sentence: "He immediately thinks of XYZ". Is it proper to say "This *is* a mistake", or "this *was* a mistake"? The character is trying to think of a happy image to sedate negative thoughts. The image he thinks of (XYZ) ends up triggering more negative thoughts; so choosing this image (XYZ) as a "happy" image was a mistake; his choice is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'This **was** a mistake'.

The thought took place in the past relative to him deciding it was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

'This **is** a mistake'.

You are writing in the present tense already ("He immediately **thinks** of XYZ").

Since you use this tense the reader is expected to understand the events they are reading as happening now.  "He realising it is a mistake" is the event you are describing, and it's happening as the reader reads it.

e.g.

'He immediately thinks of XYZ.  This is a mistake.  XYZ broke his heart in the end so why would he think of her now?  "Why can't I stop thinking about her?" he thinks.  He tries to think about puppies but he just can't picture any, only her sweet cruel face.'